# C# - Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Bson' or one of its dependencies, when my WCF service performs a Find

Tags: c#, mongodb, wcf, .net-assembly, bson

The issue I'm having is quite an unusual one. I am writing a WCF service that can perform a variety of functions on a set of collections in MongoDB.

2 of the collections are made from classes I have created locally within the WCF service, and all operations when called externally by the client complete with no dramas.

The 3rd collection is created from a class that is defined externally and I cannot access or change this code.

One of my method is to Find all documents within this collection within a defined scope and take the odd bit of information for the response to the caller. This works fine on the driver I built into my WCF service but when a client calls the service externally, (I found this out after flooding the service with trace) I receive the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Bson...' or one of its dependencies

The strange thing is, when other methods perform updates on this collection, again there are no issues and the update completes successfully.

I am drawn to think that the caller to the WCF service is missing something. It's the only explanation as to why a local driver works but calling the method externally coughs and dies.

EDIT:
So this is the code that sets up my Mongo Collections:

```
client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
server = client.GetServer();
database = server.GetDatabase(b.DatabaseName);
c1 = database.GetCollection<MyType1>("collection1");
c2 = database.GetCollection<MyType2>("collection2");
c3 = database.GetCollection<ExternalType>("collection3");
```

To return a list of records within a certain scope from a collection, I use the following:

```
var scopeQuery = Query.EQ("Scope", scopeValue);
var results = c1.Find(scopeQuery).ToList();
```

As I said, c1 and c2 are collections created from types that are local to the WCF service. If I perform a find on these then I get my documents back, no dramas.

If I perform a Find(query) on c3, the collection populated documents created by the external type (it's a class from a 3rd party DLL), then I get the recorded error, **but only when I call the method from a client**. It works fine when called from a local driver (my WCF service test application).

Note also that the following works fine, both in the driver and when called from the client:

```
var scopeQuery = Query.EQ("Scope", scopeValue);
var update = Update.Set("SomeField", someValue);
c3.Update(scopeQuery, update);
```

Any help would be welcome at this point!
Cheers!

Comment: show us some code and the point you're troubled at.

Comment: Updated, hope it helps! =]